# Force Push git commits not working after reset command

Tags: git

I checked out using this

```
get checkout 586c90b5da800dbc322c097924bb6f80b6d9d5e5
```

Which made me move from my head and then I made so many changes from there, so in order to make that as an head, I did

```
git reset --hard  586c90b5da800dbc322c097924bb6f80b6d9d5e5
```

Now if I do

```
git push
```

it says

> fatal: You are not currently on a branch. To push the history leading
>   to the current (detached HEAD) state now, use
>
> ```
> git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
> ```

if i do

```
git push origin header master
```

it says

> error: src refspec header does not match any.
>     error: failed to push some refs to 
>     `'https://github.com/something/somerepo/`

and if I do

```
git push origin master -f
```

it says everything is upto date.

How can I push my current head from which I have made couple of changes to my git repo (also, I have already done `git reset --hard  586c90b5da800dbc322c097924bb6f80b6d9d5e5`)

Comment: do you really want to push on master or do you want to eventually perform a merge request?

Answer (score 1):

Your first checkout command put you in "detached head" state -- you are on a commit, but there is no branch ("head") there. That means that any commits you make there are on an unnamed branch. Generally this isn't a good way to work, though it's possible.

Then you did a `git reset --hard` back to that commit, but since there's no branch pointer, no head was moved. Your working dir is back to commit 586c90, but that's all. Your commits after that still exist, but nothing points to them so they will be garbage-collected eventually. Note that you're still in "detached head" state here.

Now you try to do a push, but you're not on a branch. You can't push without a branch name; you'd only be pushing nameless commits to the remote, and they'd get GCed eventually there too since nothing points to them.

What you should do here is create a branch name -- either at 586c90, or at the tip of your commits (use `git log -n10 --all` to see all heads, and/or scroll through your shell window to see the last commit ID, or use `git reflog` to see the commit ID where you reset it back to 586c90). `git checkout -b new-branch` should do it. Once you have a branch name, you can push that branch to your remote.

Comment: Technically, you *can* push without a branch name on your end, because `git push` has two parts: first, send some commits if/as needed; then, ask the other Git to set some of *its* names. That's what `HEAD:refs/heads/asdf` does for instance: push commits from `HEAD`, then ask them to set their name `refs/heads/asdf`. But this is the right answer, and upvoted.